# is possible remove Jhipster Dependencies in back? why is necessary?

Tags: jhipster

is possible remove Jhipster Dependencies in back? why is necessary or recommended???

IF I REMOVE OF POM.XML appears different compilation errors.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${jhipster-dependencies.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-dependency-management -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Is it possible?**

Yes but you have to import all the dependencies yourself although nothing very difficult because most of them are already provided as Spring Boot starters. Looking at effective pom with `mvnw help:effective-pom` could help.

Then you must import maven plugins configuration.

Finally, your project will still depend on `jhipster-framework` library unless you extract only the classes your project needs.

**Is it recommended?**

For long term, managing yourself your dependencies is a good thing because major libraries like Spring Boot, Hibernate, ... support old releases for quite a long time while JHipster team supports only current major release (currently 7.x) which usually means one year.

At the beginning of your project, you will probably want to be able to follow JHipster updates. Modifying the pom.xml will make updating generated code more difficult.

Once you have written much manual code, your project is probably already too difficult to update, so cutting the dependency with JHipster will be harmless.

I found it harder to remove dependency from JHipster frontend than from backend because for instance ng-jhipster has some dependencies on Bootstrap that require some effort to remove.

Comment: if I remove the dependency 'jhipster-dependencies' altogether what do I loose?

Comment: It depends on the options you selected when generating your project but you will find out quickly: remove it and try to compile, once you got it to compile run your tests. It's that easy.